# Problems with JQuery in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call jquery function in my aspx page but it keeps giving me error message. I tried step wise debugging but still couldn't figure out anything. Kindly can anyone advise me what could be the issue. Thanks.
I keep getting the failure response "'There is a problem processing your request'

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Dtata.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dtata" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            klm();
            function klm() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dtata.aspx/Hello",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { name: 'hello' },
                    success: function (result) {
                        response(result.d);
                        Counter() //<-- CALL OTHER AJAX METHOD TO INCREASE COUNTER ON BACK END
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });
            }


            function Counter() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dtata.aspx/Counter",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });

            }

        </script>



    </form>


</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Dtata : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int _counter = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string Hello(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }

    [WebMethod]
     public int Counter(int _counter)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("I have been called");

        this._counter = this._counter +1;
     return this._counter;
     }
}
```

Comment: During an ajax request the error call is called most likely when the url is wrong.. can you access Dtata.aspx/Counter if you paste the url in your browser?

Comment: @DiegoS:- You are right. It cant access the url. What should I put as the url so that I can access the method inside my C# class?

Comment: You should add a Hello method in your c# class that takes a string name as parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

could u please change this line :

```
 data: { name: 'hello' },
```

to this :

```
 data: "{ 'name' : 'hello' }",
```

if still get error could u send it ?
if u want to know what exactly happened change this line :

```
error: function (result) {
                    alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                }
```

to

```
error: function (result) {
                    alert(result.responseText);
                }
```

and then send it's error .